# Wordpress Custom widget with radio buttons

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am developing a custom wordpress widget with admin widget options consisting of radio buttons.

The radio buttons should all have the same group, so only one option can be selected.

So far I have the following code which displays the radio buttons as required but I am unsure how to save which radio button is selected to the database.

Any advice with examples would be very helpful

Thanks

```
class example Widget extends WP_Widget {
// Set up the widget name and description.
 public function __construct() {
 $widget_options = array( 'classname' => 'widget', 'description' => 'widget 
 example' );
parent::__construct( '......', '.....', $widget_options );
}
// Create the widget output.
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
extract( $args );
// Radio buttons
$premium_jobs = $instance[ 'premium_jobs' ];
$featured_jobs = $instance[ 'featured_jobs' ];
$prem_feat_jobs = $instance[ 'prem_feat_jobs' ];

echo $before_widget; ?>
/*  widget content here */
echo $after_widget;
}
 /**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 * 
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
 public function form( $instance ) { ?>
    <input name="job" type="radio" value="premium" <?php checked( 'premium', 
 get_option( 'premium_jobs' ) ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 
 'premium_jobs' ); ?>" > 
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'premium_jobs' ) 
  ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Premium Jobs Only', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
  </p>

  <p>
    <input name="job" type="radio" value="featured" <?php checked( 
  'featured_jobs', get_option( 'featured' ) ); ?> id="<?php echo $this- 
   >get_field_id( 'featured_jobs' ); ?>" > 
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'featured_jobs' ) 
   ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Featured Jobs Only', 'text_domain' ); ?> 
   </label> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="job" type="radio" value="prem_feat" <?php checked( 
  'prem_feat_jobs', get_option( 'premfeat' ) ); ?> id="<?php echo $this- 
   >get_field_id( 'prem_feat_jobs' ); ?>" > 
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'prem_feat_jobs' ) 
    ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Premium & Featured Jobs', 'text_domain' ); ?> 
  </label> 
  </p>
<?php }

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
  $instance = array();
 // not sure what goes here

  return $instance;
  }
  }    

  function premium_job_listings_widget() { 
  register_widget( 'premium_job_Widget' );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'premium_job_listings_widget' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with your code, first of all **clean it up**. Future you will absolutely thank present you for keeping consistently clean/properly indented code, trust me - I'm still paying for past me's mistakes! It also looks like your copy/paste went a bit haywire.

First of all, you'll need a better class name for your widget that you can call when you register it, and you can clean up your constructor.

Second you can just `extract( $instance )` to define your variables on the front end.

Third, your checkboxes aren't coded properly. The `name` should be the same for each one (and it should be the field name method of the widget class), only the `value` should be different, and you run the check on the current value of the checkbox.

Forth, the **main** question at hand is that you need to define a new instance when it's saved, or nullify it if it's been emptied in the update function.

Fifth, tied in with the first point, you'll be registering your widget with the same class name you define at the beginning. So let's put all this to practice:

```
class Premium_Job_Listings_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    // Initialize Widget with Options
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'premium_job_listings_widget',
            'Premium Job Listings Widget',
            array(
                'classname'   => 'premium-job-listings-widget',
                'description' => 'List Premium Jobs in a Widget'
            )
        );
    }

    // Widget Front End
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        extract( $instance );

        echo $before_widget;
        /* Widget Content Below */
            echo "You picked [$job]"; //This will ouput "You picked [prem_feat]", etc.
        /* Widget Content Above */
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    // Widget Admin Form
    public function form( $instance ) { ?>
        <?php extract( $instance ); ?>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="premium" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'job' ); ?>" <?php checked( $job, 'premium' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'job' ); ?>" />
                <?php esc_attr_e( 'Premium Jobs Only', 'text_domain' ); ?>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="featured" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'job' ); ?>" <?php checked( $job, 'featured' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'jos' ); ?>" />
                <?php esc_attr_e( 'Featured Jobs Only', 'text_domain' ); ?>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="prem_feat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'job' ); ?>" <?php checked( $job, 'prem_feat' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'jos' ); ?>" />
                <?php esc_attr_e( 'Premium & Featured Jobs', 'text_domain' ); ?>
            </label>
        </p>
    <?php }

    // Sanitize and Save Options
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        extract( $new_instance );
        $instance = array();

        $instance['job'] = ( !empty( $job ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $job ) : null;

        return $instance;
    }
}

function premium_job_listings_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Premium_Job_Listings_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'premium_job_listings_widget' );
```

The code above will give you a widget that looks like this in the admin:

[image: Admin Form of the Widget]

And like this on the front end:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Xhynk for the advice and the solution. All is now working as desired.